# Admob for iphone Apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, admob, ads, adwhirl

I know how to use Admob in iphone apps infact I have used in many application. But I am completely unaware about **how publisher id is generated for iphone apps** from website.

Today I have registered a new account with admob.com. Now where I have to go further for publisher id ?
I have just click this link: http://www.admob.com/my_sites/create_site.

Please see below screenshot. There is a field to enter Appstore URL. **But how can i put my appstore url in development phase ?** My application is still in development phase.

Am I at the wrong place ? Or only publisher id is required from any other place.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure App Store URL is a required field? Perhaps you could leave it blank, then come back and fill it in when your app launches?

Comment: Yeah I am 90% sure its not a required field. But can i add it later ? If yes then will be my publisher id changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa). Select *Manage Applications* and create or select your app in development. Then you can see the AppStore-Link (click *View in App Store*).

Comment: Is it really required to fill apstore url ?

Comment: bold fields are required, so I guess the appstore url is not required

Comment: you can also add the appstore url later